# Force to rebuild gentoo packages which have been merged as dependency

Tags: linux, package-management, gentoo

How can I upgrade (emerge) packages which came as dependency and which I do not want to add to the worldfile as selected packages?

**Example**

The package `media-libs/jpeg` was installed as dependency of `dev-java/icedtea-bin`.
`eix` shows, that there is a newer version available:

```
$ eix media-libs/jpeg
[U] media-libs/jpeg
     Available versions:  
     (62)   6b-r9 ~6b-r11
     (0)    8d ~9 ~9-r1
       {static-libs ABI_MIPS="n32 n64 o32" ABI_X86="32 64 x32"}
     Installed versions:  6b-r9(62)(13:39:26 12/21/13)
     Homepage:            http://jpegclub.org/ http://www.ijg.org/
     Description:         Library to load, handle and manipulate images in the JPEG format
```

But `# emerge --update --newuse --deep --with-bdeps=y @world --keep-going`
 did not `upgrade media-libs/jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

Though there is a newer jpeg version, it is under different slot. 
In most cases it means that it's incompatible with the version you have and thus emerge doesn't upgrade your version to a newer one as icedtea-bin depends on media-libs/jpeg specifying the slot 62 and media-libs/jpeg-8d will not satisfy this dependency.